# How to change the user agent profile of edge in VBA(Selenium)

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, microsoft-edge

I have the below code to access a site and get to another page, but I need the code to set the user agent profile of the "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4501.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/91.0.866.0" before it accesses the site.

I haven't been able to find a way to do this in VBA.

```
Sub idash_test()
    
    Set cd = New Selenium.EdgeDriver
    Dim ls As Selenium.SelectElement
    Dim rp As Selenium.SelectElement
    

    
    cd.Start "edge"
    cd.Get "http://idash.uhc.com/#/"
    Set ls = cd.FindElementByCss("#sel_viewas_001492341").AsSelect
    ls.SelectByValue "000791032"
    cd.FindElementByLinkText("Reports").Click
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))
    cd.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/div/span/nav/ul/li[1]/a").Click
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))
    cd.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/div/span/nav/ul/li[1]/ul/li[2]/a").Click
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))
    cd.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/div/span/nav/ul/li[1]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[1]/a").Click
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))

End Sub
```

Comment: I've only found Python, java, PHP codes for this. Nothing on VBA

Comment: Assuming you can automate Edge then [manually set this up](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/change-user-agent/368448/#close) in a saved profile then launch that profile via selenium. This isn't in-session switching but does that suit your needs?

Comment: I searched a lot and made some tests but all failed. `driver.AddArgument "--user-agent=foo"` which works in Chrome still can't work in Edge. And setting profile seems not working with Edge either. I suggest you can open an issue in [SeleniumBasic GitHub](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/issues) about this.

Comment: @YuZhou I have opened the issue on the SeleniumBasic GitHub page, If i do get a answer there, I will update this thread, The reason I need the change in user agent profile is that the site I'm trying to access is cloaked to Bot's, so all elements on the page are hidden. If anyone has another workaround it would be helpful !!

Comment: 1) How do you know changing the UA header is sufficient? There are a number of ways selenium automation is detected 2) Did you try my suggestion? Unsure if Yu tried that and what the fail reason was.  If specific to Edge for example which I have never tried automating though believe Chromium based 3) AFAIK Selenium Basic is no longer maintained so responses unlikely though may come from others rather than author

Comment: I tried that. Changing user agent in F12 devtools only works when you open the devtools and it can't be saved in a profile.

Comment: Which leaves ugly UIAutomation as a possible option or more simply checking if XHR is an option.